# GLEW linking errors

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

Im trying to put together a GLSL example program from a website, just so i can get a feel for shaders.

The shader example program is from http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/glsl/1_setup.html#DL

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TheLightingExperiment2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewLinkProgram

1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewAttachShader

1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCreateProgram

1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCompileShader

1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewShaderSource

1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCreateShader

1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewDeleteProgram

1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewDeleteShader

1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewDetachShader

1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewUseProgram

1>C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\TheLightingExperiment2\Debug\TheLightingExperiment2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The errors appear to be from glew not linking correctly. But i following glew's documentation for linking glew @ http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html

And it still gives me these errors. I have put **glew32.lib** in linker->input. I have put the the **glew32.lib** into the VC lib directory, as well as the glew includes in the VC include directory. From googleing my problem, this seems to be the resolution, but its not working for me.

Comment: These linking errors have nothing to do with GLSL, shaders, or anything of the like. It's just a failure with linking to GLEW, which you use to load OpenGL.

Comment: How can i resolve these errors?

Comment: [#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787376/lnk2001-error-opengl-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Yeah, that was the error that I had also. you need to include "opengl32.lib" into your linker settings.

Answer (score 9):

Save yourself a *lot* of trouble and just add `glew.c` to your project. Make sure you `#define GLEW_STATIC`, and everything will be fine. It is not worth it trying to link to GLEW dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same linking problem using VS.

It turned out that you should use Win32 lib instead of x64 ones

Answer (score 1):

Build glew with the GLEW_BUILD preprocessor directive ( i.e. glew project settings -> c/c++ -> preprocessor -> additional definitions)