# LNK2001 error opengl visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, lnk2019, lnk2001

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

And I have got this error message:

```
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewUseProgram   C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewUseProgram   C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGetProgramInfoLog    C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGetProgramiv C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewLinkProgram  C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewAttachShader C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGetShaderInfoLog C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGetShaderiv  C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCompileShader    C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewShaderSource C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   19  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCreateShader C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   20  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCreateProgram    C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\InitShader.obj  lab22
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewVertexAttribPointer  C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   22  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewEnableVertexAttribArray  C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   23  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGetAttribLocation    C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   24  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBufferData   C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBindBuffer   C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGenBuffers   C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   27  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBindVertexArray  C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   28  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGenVertexArrays  C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   29  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0 referenced in function _main    C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   30  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewExperimental   C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\lab22\lab22.obj   lab22
Error   31  error LNK1120: 21 unresolved externals  C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Tugas\Smst5\Komgraf\lab\lab22\Debug\lab22.exe   lab22
```

this is my program

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glut32.lib")

#include "include\Angel.h"

const int NumPoints = 3;

void
init( void )
{
// Specifiy the vertices for a triangle
vec2 vertices[3] = {
    vec2( -0.75, -0.75 ), vec2( 0.0, 0.75 ), vec2( 0.75, -0.75 )
};

// Create a vertex array object
GLuint vao[1];
glGenVertexArrays( 1, vao );
glBindVertexArray( vao[0] );


// Create and initialize a buffer object
GLuint buffer;
glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

// Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader21.glsl", "fshader21.glsl" );
glUseProgram( program );

// Initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
   glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                       BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); // white background
}

void 
display( void )
{
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );     // clear the window
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumPoints );    // draw the points
glFlush();
}

void
keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
switch ( key ) {
case 033:
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
    break;
}
}

int 
main( int argc, char **argv )
{
glutInit( &argc, argv );
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA );
glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );

glutCreateWindow( "Red Triangle" );
glewExperimental=GL_TRUE; 
glewInit();    
init();

glutDisplayFunc( display );
glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

I think I already install glut,freeglut and glew correctly, I already edit my linker but its still error. I put glut, freeglut, and glew folder in my project and in my visual studio but it still show that error. for the first project I can compile, now I'm using Angle.h and it cannot compile

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using pre-processor hacks to link against the rest of your libraries, I imagine you probably want to do this:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
```

Usually you would use project settings to set up linked libraries, but a lot of tutorials use the pre-processor directive because it avoids having to walk users through configuring Visual Studio projects (which differs with every new version).